# Target of URI doesn't exist problem how to solve?

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.

I installed cloud firestore in pubspec yaml file but I still get this error

Comment: Exactly what does your `pubspec.yaml` file look like?  When you run `flutter pub get`, are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` and then run `flutter pub get` in the console.

I think this will work.

Comment: it doesnt work i tried

Comment: try closing project and restarting your pc, this can work in your case